# Sto-stone puzzle

Tags: grid-deduction

**Sto-stone** is a puzzle made by [Nikoli.](//www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/sto-stone.html) Here are the rules:

> 1. You must color the cells with black with the following rules:
> 2. There are rooms enclosed in bold lines. The number on the room shows the number of continuous black cells in that room. No number means any number of black cells.
> 3. Black cells cannot connect across bold lines, vertically or horizontally.
> 4. Stones (or the black cells) must be dropped straight down, and the stones must fill the bottom half of the grid without empty cells. (Dropped stones may cross and connect across bold lines)
>
> <sub>(Example in the link above)</sub>

This is your real challenge:

[image: stostone]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this solution:

> Each column should have 4 stones so when dropped the bottom half is coloured[image]

Comment: Great answer!! :D

Comment: Isn't it also a solution if the bottom left corner is black, and the cell two above is white?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution for this puzzle (updated, because as determined previously I don't know how to read):

> [image]

Comment: Rule 3: "Black cells cannot connect across bold lines, vertically or horizontally."

Comment: My wifi is apparently bad and didn't realize gabbo had already posted!!